# Php - array multidimensional usando for ou foreach

Tags: php

Gente, preciso de ajuda, observem os exemplos abaixo:

```
$cores = array (‘vermelhas’,’amarelas’,’verdes’)

$ frutas = array(
                         array (‘maçã’,’morango’,’cereja’,’acerola’),
                         array (‘banana’,’melão’),
                         array (‘abacate’,’kiwi’,’pera’))
```

Preciso exibir os arrays de cima e logo em seguida os arrays muktidimensionais em formato de lista, eles devem ser exibidos como o exemplo abaixo, usando for ou foreach:

```
Vermelhas
• maça
• morango
• cereja
• acerola

Amarelas
• banana
• melão

Verdes
• abacate
• kiwi
• pera
```

Comment: Qual a ligação da primeira array com a segunda? Porque se for pela ordem, as "verdes" serão "banana e melão".

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, segue um exemplo no Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/5rcmxwPq

Cada índice do array **$cores** possui uma lista de frutas, que serão exibidas em formato de lista .

no **foreach** do php, o formato é o seguinte: **foreach( $lista as $indice => $valores)**.

Dessa forma, o nome da core será o **$indice**, e as frutas estarão em **$valores**, precisando um outro foreach em **$valores** para exibir cada valor na lista de frutas.

Comment: Oi, bom dia! Preciso que o array unidimensional fique separado do multidimensional. Porque esse eh apenas um exemplo, no código original, no lugar das cores tem uma frase.

Comment: Nesse caso, teriamos nesse formato : https://pastebin.com/BR59aC46

Não seria muito recomendado fazer dessa forma, pois a cor não está diretamente ligada à lista de frutas, mas funciona sem problemas.

Comment: Obrigada, vou testar assim q chegar em casa.

Answer (score -1):

Desculpa, inverti, o correto é:

```
$cores =array (‘vermelhas’,’amarelas’,’verdes’)
```

Comment: Use o link de edição em sua pergunta para adicionar outras informações. O botão Publicar resposta deve ser usado apenas para concluir respostas à pergunta. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/180940)

Comment: Estou pelo celular e naoa tinha visto, obrigada.